# How to convert date format to UTC in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, performance, date, simpledateformat

How to convert date format `"2021-02-28 13:38:00.597+0000"` to `"Mon, Feb 28,2021 15:25:00 UTC"` UTC format in Scala?

Comment: Well, this is possible through the use of `java.time`, but we cannot change the day of week (2021-02-28 was in fact a Sunday). If it's just the format, please show us your own effort (doesn't have to work, of course) and I'll try to give an answer.

Comment: Oh, and the times of day should match, too, shouldn't they?

Comment: Referring to your tag: you don’t want to use `SimpleDateFormat`. It was a notoriously troublesome class and is now fortunately long outdated. As @deHaar said, you want to use java.time.

Comment: Also you want to search before asking a question here. And in your question tell us what your search brought up and how it was insufficient for you. Both so we know you’ve done an effort (funnily it tends to make folks here much more willing to do one) and to let us know more precisely what you still need to know.

Comment: If the UTC offset in the first string is not `+0000` (say, it is `-0700`), what do you want to happen? Conversion to UTC? An error being reported?

Comment: Could you live with the trailing text being `GMT` instead of `UTC`? Asking because the built-in [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) seems to give you what you want only with the mentioned difference.

Comment: TBH I wonder why someone upvoted this question. I rather considered downvoting as unresearched and/or close-voring as neeing more focus. Please don’t take it personally. It takes a bit to learn to use Stack Overflow in a good way. Please keep on.

Comment: There are two good answers (of which I’d probably go by the one by deHaar). If you want to be able to format an `OffsetDateTime`, which would make sense, you may as a third option use a formatter defined as `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("EEE, MMM d, uuuu HH:mm:ss ") .appendOffset("+HHMM", "UTC") .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)` It gave `Sun, Feb 28, 2021 13:38:00 UTC`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an older Java version prior to Java 8, it's best to use the [DateTimeFormat](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) from joda-time. BTW, the `+0000` zone offset is for UTC, so I could have omitted `withZoneUTC()`, but I still used it for the first date just to be safe:

```
  val oldDateString = "2021-02-28 13:38:00.597+0000"
  val OldFormat     = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
  val NewFormat     = "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

  val formatterOld = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(OldFormat)
  val formatterNew = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(NewFormat)

  val dt              = formatterOld.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(oldDateString)
  val dateStringInUTC = formatterNew.withZoneUTC().print(dt)

  println(dt)              // 2021-02-28T13:38:00.597Z
  println(dateStringInUTC) // Sun, Feb 28, 2021 13:38:00 UTC
```

**UPDATE**: For Java 8 and newer, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API is your friend. Similarly, `withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)` was not really needed:

```
  val oldDateString = "2021-02-28 13:38:00.597+0000"
  val OldFormat     = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"
  val NewFormat     = "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

  val formatterOld = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(OldFormat)
  val formatterNew = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(NewFormat)

  val zdt             = ZonedDateTime.parse(oldDateString, formatterOld)
  val dateStringInUTC = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(formatterNew)

  println(zdt)             // 2021-02-28T13:38:00.597Z
  println(dateStringInUTC) // Sun, Feb 28, 2021 13:38:00 UTC
```

**UPDATE**: Switched to using `ZoneId.of("UTC")` instead of `ZoneOffset.UTC` because the latter does not get the `String` `UTC` printed at the end, even though `ZoneOffset` extends `ZoneId`, as @deHaar mentioned.

Comment: The [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is in maintenance-mode. For Java 6 and Java 7, I suggest using the back-port of most of the *java.time* functionality from Java 8+: [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). The back-port has nearly the same API as *java.time*, so eventually migration from the back-port to the built-in *java.time* may involve little more than changing `import` statements. All three projects (Joda-Time, java.time, and ThreeTen-Backport) are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Answer (score 4):

If you could use `java.time`, you would need

- a `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing `String`s with the format of your input example, which is quite near to ISO standard, but is missing the `'T'` between date and time of day
- another `DateTimeFormatter` for outputting the temporal content in the desired format, which includes (English) abbreviations for day of week and month of year
- an `OffsetDateTime` for parsing the `String` with the first `DateTimeFormatter` and
- a `ZonedDateTime` for the temporal value in UTC

This is how I would do it in Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String
    String utcDatetimeString = "2021-02-28 13:38:00.597+0000";
    // prepare a formatter that can parse a String of this format
    DateTimeFormatter dtfIn = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSxxxx",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH
                                    );
    // parse it to an OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(utcDatetimeString, dtfIn);
    // then convert it to a ZonedDateTime applying UTC zone
    ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // prepare a formatter that produces the desired output
    DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "EEE, MMM dd, uuuu HH:mm:ss zzz",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH
                                    );
    // and print the ZonedDateTime using the formatter
    System.out.println(zdt.format(dtfOut));
}
```

Output:

```
Sun, Feb 28, 2021 13:38:00 UTC
```

Comment: Nice! Using `ZoneId.of("UTC")`  is important here. I was using `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead, which led to throwing `DateTimeException: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal ...` when using `OffsetDateTime` so I switched to  `ZonedDateTime` but then I could not get the `UTC` `String` getting printed, so I had to manually insert it.

Comment: I got that one thrown some time ago, then I decided to always use `ZoneId`s for `ZonedDateTime`s even though `ZoneOffset extends ZoneId`. I think both our answers add value here! Yes, there must be a zone with an id, an offset alone is not sufficient (though +0000 means UTC in literally all cases).